# Spring 3.1.1 and Cache configuration issue

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, caching, jakarta-ee

I'm testing the Spring cache and, this is my context file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="simpleCacheManager"/>

    <bean id="simpleCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean">
                    <property name="name" value="alfresco"/>
                </bean> 
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean">
                    <property name="name" value="alfresco_article"/>
                </bean> 
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean">
                    <property name="name" value="alfresco_action"/>
                </bean>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I added all required library but, I cannot validate the library because Eclipse still tells me that AOPAlliance.jar and org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar are missing.

The error is:

Multiple annotations founds at this line: class org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean not found.

SOLVED changing to org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean

but, calling the url this happens:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [configuration-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [configuration-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
```

aop-alliance.jar and org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar are both in classpath.

Any clue?

Thanks, 
Andrea

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Double-check that org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar is indeed on the classpath. Both Eclipse validation and the error point at this issue.

UPDATE: I've checked, and you are right. `ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean` seems to be removed since 3.1.0.M1 and is possibly replaced by `ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean` in the same package. I wasn't able to find any proof in the release notes yet. However, if you change the bean class name for your caches to `ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean`, it does seem to work fine.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean">
    <property name="name" value="alfresco"/>
</bean>
```

**UPDATE2: Yes, indeed `ConcurrentCacheFactoryBean` has been [renamed](https://build.springsource.org/browse/SPR-MASTER-19/commit) to `ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean`.** They just didn't get around to update the tutorial.

Comment: Yeah, it works, but still a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils. Is it possible that something else has been changed? The class is available on classpath

Comment: `AopNamespaceUtils` should be in your `spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar` - make sure you include it. Besides, this hasn't got a lot to do with cache configuration ;-)

Comment: `spring-aop` depends on `aopalliance-1.0.jar`. Make sure you have it.