# Concurrent BeanFactory? Does it exist?

Tags: spring, concurrency, javabeans, factory-pattern

Is there a BeanFactory implementation which loads and caches every bean concurrently?

In a perfect scenario I want every bean to run in a different thread. Is it possible right now? or do I need to write my own implementation for this?

Scenario:
Every bean has a message queue channel allocated and is communicating asynchronously. In default implementation all beans are in the same thread. Meaning that if I have let's say 50 beans, each getting like 10 message per second with heavy processing soon I will have a latency on when these messages are being processed.

Comment: why? just ensure that your beans are threadsafe and then let their clients use them on as much threads as they want

Comment: Do you really want a concurrent BeanFactory because the factory just _instantiates_ the beans, it doesn't "run" them.  Can you edit your post to provide more information about what you mean by run?

Comment: I updated the question with a scenario to give more explanations on what I mean

Answer (score 1):

I think solution is to use `ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean`

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean.html

eg.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="default"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

For some example of how to use look into:

- [Spring 3.1.1 and Cache configuration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978731/spring-3-1-1-and-cache-configuration-issue)
- http://www.silviowangler.ch/tag/spring/
- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Answer (score 0):

Today I looked into Spring Integration and found that it kind of fits the scenario. I can use ExecutorChannel to process the messages in different thread one at a time. Actually I can implement the scenario quite easily using BlockingQueue itself. Anyway, thanks for attention!

BTW, if anyone is interested, this is what I came up with:

```
Scenario for an individual Bean:
Allocate a blocking queue

Spawn a background thread which:
    Blocks until message is available in the MQ channel
    When message is available:
        Put a message inside a blocking queue and block until queue is not full
    Repeat the sequence

Spawn a background thread which:
    Blocks until queue is not empty
    Processes a message when it's available in the queue
    Removes a message from the queue indicating that processing is done
    Repeat the sequence
```